# .checked with javascript not changing html input radio

Tags: javascript, radio-group, checked, setattribute

I have a set of radio inputs.

I'm trying to change the input to be checked, when I use `.checked = true`, console log shows that it is true.

But the radio doesn't display checked. On the other hand if I use `.setAttribute('checked', 'checked')` then it displays checked and `.getAttribute('checked')` is checked but I cant run the following commands.

```js
function galleryOut() {

  const backgroundChange = () => {
    landingBackground.classList.remove('opaque-bg');
    landingPage.classList.remove('blur-bg');

    console.log('gallery slides out');

    galleryRadioMenu.classList.remove('active');
    galleryClose.classList.remove('active');

    pictureSlideBox.classList.remove('active');

    console.log('sliding menu out');
  };
  const zIndexChange = () => {
    galleryPage.style.zIndex = '-5';

    console.log('removing z-index');
  };
  const firstRadioChange = () => {
    pictureSlideBox.style.transform = null;

    allRadio.forEach(radio => radio.setAttribute('checked', ''));
    firstRadio.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  };

  if (firstRadio.getAttribute('checked') === 'checked') {

    backgroundChange();

    setTimeout(zIndexChange, 3000);

  } else if (firstRadio.getAttribute('checked') === null) {

    firstRadioChange();

    setTimeout(backgroundChange, 3000);
    setTimeout(zIndexChange, 5000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-radio">
  <form id="menu" class="align-left slide-in">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="slide1" name="slider" title="pic1" data-key="1" checked>
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="slide2" name="slider" title="pic2" data-key="2">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="slide3" name="slider" title="pic3" data-key="3">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="slide4" name="slider" title="pic4" data-key="4">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="slide5" name="slider" title="pic5" data-key="5">
  </form>
</div>
```

Am I missing something out here? What's the difference between .checked and .setAttribute('checked', 'checked')?

Comment: have you tried `firstRadio.checked = true`?

Comment: Reading and changing the `checked` state of a radio/checkbox control has to be done via this control's `checked` property, not by reading the related HTML element's `checked` attribute because even though the attribute might have been initially set, the control meanwhile could have been unchecked.

Comment: Btw the provided script features several syntax errors and already by that does fail. And more important, when is `galleryOut` supposed to be executed?